# Turn on again old expandable menu

Tags: admin-menu

In the latest WP the admin interface is changed and you have a popup submenu. I really liked the old version better with expandable menu. Is it somehow possible to get that back again for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, believe so. Try this (enqueue in admin styles):

**Show sub-menus at all times**

```
#adminmenu .wp-submenu,
.folded #adminmenu .wp-submenu {
     display: block !important;
}
```

**Hide Pop-up Navs**

```
.wp-submenu.sub-open {
     display: none !important;
}
```

That should get you started with it, otherwise you can go to **wp-admin.dev.css** and edit the navigation there, starting at line c. 1519. Hope that helps..